# How to initialize child elements in ContainerView Tag?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How do I initialize child elements in a ContainerView?

for example, this template:

```
{{#view Ember.CardLayout}}

  {{view Ember.TextField}}

{{/view}}
```

and this view:

```
/**
* [Table description]
* @type {[type]}
*/
Ember.CardLayout = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    title: null,
    // ??? 
    childViews: ['testView'],
    testView: Ember.Checkbox.create(),
    render: function(buffer) {
      this.forEachChildView(function(view) {
        view.renderToBuffer(buffer);
      });
    }
});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with [the documentation](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.ContainerView&src=false). That contains a number of examples which you might find helpful. I'd recommend something like this:

```
App.cardLayout = Ember.ContainerView.create({
  title: null,
  childViews: ['testView'],
  testView: Ember.Checkbox.create()
});
```

and then a template

```
{{view App.cardLayout}}
```

You can then add and remove views by manipulating the `App.cardLayout.get('childViews')` object.

Comment: thanks.   but i want use markup style write layout code,because it's look clear . so i want  custom Cardlayout control to collect sub control and output .